# MySQL - How do I insert an additional where clause into this full-text search

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I want to add a WHERE clause to a full text search query (to limit to past 24 hours), but wherever I insert it I get Low Level Error. Is it possible to add the clause and if so, how? Here is the code WITHOUT the where clause:

```
        $query = "SELECT *, MATCH (story_title) AGAINST ('$query' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
AS Relevance FROM stories WHERE MATCH (story_title) AGAINST ('+$query' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
 HAVING Relevance > 0.2 ORDER BY Relevance DESC, story_time DESC;
```

Comment: Could you perhaps add some linebreaks in there? It's tough to read as it is.

Comment: And between the WHERE & HAVING clause I presume...

Comment: Can you clarify where you are trying to insert the `WHERE` expression and what error you are getting?

Comment: thw where clause is after the asterisk. The error is "Low Level Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'MATCH (story_title) AGAINST ('query' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS Relevance FROM dug_stor' at line 1"

Answer (score 5):

First, some tips about asking questions:

- **Use line breaks.** PHP supports string literals with line breaks, unlike some languages like Java.  Formatting your SQL makes it easier to read, debug, and maintain.
- **Show the SQL.**  You have embedded PHP variable expansion in that query, which is irrelevant to your question.  This just makes it more difficult for people to decipher what you're trying to ask.  Show the code you want to debug, not the code that generates the code.

Now about your query:

- You can't just put an extra `WHERE` clause anywhere.  Add extra terms to your existing `WHERE` clause with the `AND` operator.
- Embedding a call to validate the same `$_GET` parameter multiple times in the same query seems wasteful.  Use a variable to preserve the result of validating the parameter.
- Take advantage of [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).  Put the conditions that are least expensive to evaluate (e.g. those that benefit from a conventional index) leftmost.
- MySQL fulltext search in [boolean mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-boolean.html) does not return relevance.  You have to use the [natural language mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-natural-language.html) to get the relevance value between 0 and 1.
- Putting conditions in the `HAVING` clause instead of the `WHERE` clause makes it easier because you can use column aliases you defined in the `SELECT` list, but it may make the query perform worse.  `HAVING` is for placing conditions on groups to include after a `GROUP BY` clause.  `WHERE` is for placing conditions on rows to include in the query result.
- Rows are automatically sorted in order of relevance if you use `MATCH()` in natural language mode in the `WHERE` clause.  If the chance of a tie is low, you might be able to skip your `ORDER BY` clause, and make the query even more efficient.

Here's how I would write this code:

```
$q = validate_input($_GET["q"]);
$bsearch = $pdo->quote("+{$q}");
$nlsearch = $pdo->quote($q);
$stories_table = $config["db"]["pre"] . "stories";
$offset = validate_input(($_GET["page"]-1)*10);

$query = "
  SELECT *, MATCH (story_title) AGAINST ({$nlsearch}) AS Relevance 
  FROM {$stories_table} 
  WHERE story_time > time()-86400
    AND MATCH (story_title) AGAINST ({$bsearch} IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
    AND MATCH (story_title) AGAINST ({$nlsearch}) > 0.2
  LIMIT {$offset}, 10";
```

Comment: Can you give any more detail that "doesn't work either"?  It's hard to suggest anything further.  Can you edit your question above and add the exact query you're executing (after all PHP code has produced it) and the exact error message?  Also some details like what version of MySQL and how you're executing the query from PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have two `WHERE` clauses in there:

```
SELECT * 
WHERE story_time > time()-86400 
AND MATCH (story_title) AGAINST ('".validate_input($_GET['q'])."' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
AS Relevance 
FROM ".$config['db']['pre']."stories 
WHERE MATCH (story_title) AGAINST ('+".validate_input($_GET['q'])."' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
HAVING Relevance > 0.2 
ORDER BY Relevance DESC, story_time DESC LIMIT
```

Should be something like this:

```
SELECT *, MATCH (story_title) AGAINST ('".validate_input($_GET['q'])."' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
AS Relevance 
FROM ".$config['db']['pre']."stories 
WHERE MATCH (story_title) AGAINST ('+".validate_input($_GET['q'])."' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
HAVING Relevance > 0.2 
AND story_type > time() - 86400
ORDER BY Relevance DESC, story_time DESC LIMIT
```